# Share directives/elements over sockets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a directive called `shareable`, which assigns a unique ID to the element that the directive is assigned to. It also sets a click handler so that once a user clicks the element some code is executed.

The goal of all of this is to share actions executed on the specific element. Once a user clicks on the element, it should highlight on multiple clients that share the same scope (data is being exchanged through WebSockets). I'm having trouble, however, assigning an ID to these elements that all clients have in common.

Is there a way to generate some kind of a "hashcode" (for example) or unique ID for the elements, that can be the same across all the connected clients?